# Like-Box social plugin not working

Tags: facebook-page, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I have a Facebook page and want to use the like-box social plugin on it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

However my code doesn't want to pull up my page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="{pagename}" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```